# Convert formatted date back to unix

Tags: php, date, time

Which function would I use to convert custom formatted dates back to Unix Epoch time?

For example:

```
("Ymd") -> ("U");
```

I looked at `date("U",strtotime("20140525"));` , but I'm not sure how to fit in the original format `Ymd`.

How does that function know that the input format is YYYYMMDD, because it looks like it works.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', '20140525');
echo $date->format('U');
```